# I want to make a PolygonSelector from matplotlib to embed in tkinter frame. When i did that, the canvas freeze

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, backend, matplotlib-widget

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCsmL.png)

```
from matplotlib.widgets import AxesWidget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.widgets import PolygonSelector
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase

def callback_function(event):
print(event.x,event.y)

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
frame1=tk.Frame()
frame1.pack()
figure = plt.figure()
ax=figure.add_subplot(111)
PolygonSelector(ax,callback_function)

# canvas=FigureCanvasBase()

axes_widget=AxesWidget(ax)
FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=frame1).get_tk_widget().pack()
axes_widget.connect_event('button_press_event', callback_function)

window.mainloop()
```

i have tried the PolygonSelector function to work itself and it works fine. But i want to embed the PolygonSelector widget to my window.